# How can I get subFloder's items displayed on PowerApps?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I'd like to have content in sharepoint's sub-folder to be displayed on PowerApps Gallery,
I tried
"Items = ClearCollect(testDoc,Filter(Documents,'Folder path'="Documents/General/Use Cases and similar activities/A-EMA/"))"
But it doesn't work.
Nothing displayed but only warnings.
here is the pic of what I'd like to show in my gallery.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8rLM.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Connect your Sharepoint Site to PowerApps

Second: Set up a Variable to avoid Delegation Issues and get aTable

```
Set(docs;Dokuments)
```

Third: Put the following code into items of your Gallery.

```
Filter(
docs;
IsFolder = false && Path = "Freigegebene Dokumente/Subfolder1/Subfolder2/")
```

Dependent on your language change 'IsFolder' to 'Istordner' and 'Path' to 'Ordnerpfad'.

it is working fine with me, but my folder names are all without spaces, so if you still encounter problems, please try to change your folder names

Comment: I tried and I realized a thing that may cause my failure: I tried to connet 2 galleries to 2 different sharepoint site, one is private and one is public, the private one still doesn't work while the public one's files are displayed in gallery. So I'm wondering if the access of Sharepoint site can cause this failure?

Comment: Check out your PowerApp under Approvals: There is a statement, that for Data Connections all users must have access. Same goes for the Flows.

Comment: Hi I tested today and it is so stranged that all sub folders work in this way except the one I need... even folder name with space works...no idea what happens

Comment: When the code is working with the other galleries and sharepoint sites, it really must be within your private sharepoint site. there are a lot of options, while the site is not shown and without more information it is not possible to determine the reason.
- check site permissions
- check if you have renamed the site (sharepoint uses always the origin)

Comment: Where to put the code `Set(docs;Dokuments)` in the powerapp? On OnStart, OnVisible...?